# Pandas get columns that contains an exact string name

Tags: python, pandas

This line of code lets me extract the columns whose name contains the substring `a`.

```
data = {"a":[1], "a1":[2]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("a")])
```

How do I extract the columns that contain *exactly* the string `a`? E.g.

```
print(df.loc[:,df.columns.str == "a"])
```

Comment: do you mean `df['a']`?

Comment: df[['a']] to return a df and df['a'] for series

Comment: god all these syntaxes has made me forget the simplest pandas syntax. TY.